# Posicionar cursor no final do texto ao clicar em input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tem como fazer com que todas vez que clico na input o cursor vá para o final dela?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que nessa imagem ele está antes do 1 e queria que toda vez que clicar na input ele va para o final.

Comment: Talvez essa questão te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Comment: As alternativas dos companheiros a cima não funciona em alguns navegadores, se tiver utilizando js puro pode fazer uma função que é executada no onfocus do input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, a maneira mais simples, meio "força bruta" é re-escrever o valor do input com ele próprio. Isso obriga o cursor a ir para o final.

Testa mexer o cursor com as setas e depois clicar nele.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="algo para testar" />
```

Comment: Atualmente, não funciona no Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Outra alternativa, com Javascript:

```html
<input onfocus="this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = 500;" value="Olá texto">
```

Comment: Pra mim isso não funcionou.

Comment: Usa Chrome @jbueno? Uso safari e firefox, é o que tinha testado, depois que falou vi que pelo chrome realmente não funciona. Vou investigar o porquê.

Comment: Sim, uso Chrome. Também achei bem estranho, porque deveria ser a forma correta de se fazer. De qualquer forme, testei no safari e ff e funcionou, então fica meu voto.